# Operator overloading python

Tags: python

```
> class divnum:
>     def __init__(self,num):
>         self.nums=num
>     def __div__(self,other):
>         return self.nums/other.nums 
> a=divnum(5)  
> b=divnum(1)
> answer= (a/b)
```

This error "builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'divnum' and 'divnum'".
what i wrong?

Comment: What version of python? This works in 2.7

Comment: Probably python version 3.x Since it would do float division by default, which is implemented by `__truediv__`

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  It's a perfectly reasonable beginner question, and one on which it's easy to be misled by lots of examples on the web which are Py 2-centric.

Comment: @user3286067 if M4rtini answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the answer by clicking on the "v" at the left of it. This way, future readers will know it is the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is Python 3.x

To implement the division operator for a class, there are two methods: `__floordiv__` and `__truediv__`. integer and float division respectively.

If you only implement one of them, you get the TypeError you experienced when trying to do the other.

In python 3.x the default is float division, unless you use `//`. So you should implement `__truediv__` in  your class unless you only want integer division to be possible.

I don't have python 3.x myself, so i can't test this. But i think this should be right.

```
class divnum:
    def __init__(self,num):
         self.nums=num
    def __truediv__(self,other):
         return self.nums/other.nums

    def __floordiv__(self, other):
        return self.nums//other.nums
```

Comment: `__truediv__` and `__floordiv__`, not `__truediv__` and `__div__`.

Comment: Thank you for answer.  I can run __truediv__.    Thank you very much